# Informatica powercenter shell not working

Tags: informatica

I tried to run **command** task to changes clear contents of a file using .sh commands and printf, but neither one isn't working. where as I'm able to run mkdir,copy and rm are working.
 Just wondering should I have to change any configuration settings for clearing and write contents of a file.

Comment: Did you check the logs of Command Task, as if command fails there should be some logs. Also change config to fail the wf if command task fails and see the logs.

Comment: Can you post the exact commands you are trying to run? A simple `cp /dev/null filename` should be enough.

Comment: Sudo to your informatica user then run tbmhe commands and youll be able to see the error... otherwise redirect all output from the shell script to a logfile and check there... usually its a permissions issue on the file / directory where you're trying to make a change